# Problem with LD_LIBRARY_PATH, program can't find a libraray.

Tags: path

I have already asked this question on stackoverflow, but it's also a linux related question and somebody here might know a solution. Hope it's okay.

Problem is that I can't run 3D visualisation in Paraprof program on ARM Linux. 
I am running a small cluster (8 nodes) using armhf Debian Wheezy 7.1 with OpenMPI.

I am using Tau OpenMPI profiling tool and it's got a very nice visualising tool called Paraprof.

I have a problem with 3D visualisation with paraprof. When I try to run it it says that:

```
/home/cluster/tool/tau-2.22.2/lib/libjogl_drihack.so :/home/cluster/tool/tau-2.22.2/lib/libjogl_drihack.so cannot open shared object: No such file or directory
```

I think it's a problem with libraries paths settings, because the path is doubled. Interestingly libjogl_drihack.so is in this directory. LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set correctly as:

```
/usr/local/lib/:/home/cluster/tools/tau-2.22.2/arm_linux/lib/
```

OpenGL is installed (I can run glxinfo) and all libjogl packages.

Attaching screenshots. https://www.dropbox.com/s/x54xpo5c2kjzew8/tau1.png https://www.dropbox.com/s/mimze22pcl6vxkq/tau2.png

Some more info:

```
root@master:~# ldd
/home/cluster/tools/tau-2.22.2/arm_linux/lib/libjogl_drihack.so
    not a dynamic executable
root@master:~# ls /home/cluster/tools/tau-2.22.2/arm_linux/lib/lib*.so
/home/cluster/tools/tau-2.22.2/arm_linux/lib/libjogl_awt.so
/home/cluster/tools/tau-2.22.2/arm_linux/lib/libjogl_drihack.so
/home/cluster/tools/tau-2.22.2/arm_linux/lib/libjogl.so
/home/cluster/tools/tau-2.22.2/arm_linux/lib/libTauDisable.so
/home/cluster/tools/tau-2.22.2/arm_linux/lib/libTAUsh-depthlimit-mpi-pdt.so
/home/cluster/tools/tau-2.22.2/arm_linux/lib/libTAUsh-depthlimit-mpi-pdt-trace.so
/home/cluster/tools/tau-2.22.2/arm_linux/lib/libTAUsh-mpi-pdt.so
/home/cluster/tools/tau-2.22.2/arm_linux/lib/libTAUsh-mpi-pdt-trace.so
/home/cluster/tools/tau-2.22.2/arm_linux/lib/libTAUsh-param-mpi-pdt-profile-trace.so
/home/cluster/tools/tau-2.22.2/arm_linux/lib/libTAUsh-param-mpi-pdt.so
/home/cluster/tools/tau-2.22.2/arm_linux/lib/libTAUsh-pthread-pdt.so
/home/cluster/tools/tau-2.22.2/arm_linux/lib/libTAUsh-pthread.so
/home/cluster/tools/tau-2.22.2/arm_linux/lib/libTAUsh.so
/home/cluster/tools/tau-2.22.2/arm_linux/lib/libTAU.so
root@master:~# uname -a
Linux master 3.8.13-bone26 #1 SMP Fri Aug 16 20:56:24 UTC 2013 armv7l GNU/Linux
root@master:~#
```

OpenGL:

```
root@master:~$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string:Mesa Project
OpenGL renderer string: Software Rasterizer
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 8.0.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions
```

The configuration script for Tau, was looking for libGL.so in /usr/lib directory, on my system this file is in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf so i copied it to the /usr/lib, but still no luck. The same error persits.

Comment: Thanks for acknowledging your cross-post here, but you should have done it in the S.O. post too!

Answer (score 3):

```
/home/cluster/tools/tau-2.22.2/arm_linux/lib/libjogl_drihack.so
    not a dynamic executable
```

This means what it says.  It's one or more of:

- Not a real .so file.
- Not executable.
- Compiled for a different architecture.

Check the output of `file libjogl_drihack.so` (you need the correct path there).

I'm not an openMPI or Tau user, but I notice there is a Tau package available for armhf Wheezy (or at least, there is for raspbian).  However, I doubt this would install into `/home/cluster`, so evidently you are using something else.

If you compiled the whole thing on the system, this shouldn't happen either.  But if you copied/built the binaries from somewhere else, that's your problem (note there is more than one ARM architecture). Do you have a reason for not using the distro package?

Comment: Compiled for a different architecture is probably right — it's probably an armel library on an armhf system.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to recompile these libraries and we'll see if it works..

Comment: Recompiling jogl.1.0.0 is not so trivial on armhf as it would seem..  New jogl doesn't generate the files that I need unfortunately.